# Is there a way to send large files over UDP

Tags: python, udp

I had just started learning network programming using Python. Currently working on homework that request using UDP to send files over from client to server then back to the client. However, my codes work fine with small files but had problems with larger files.

I had found a way of using import os to find out the size of the file. So I am thinking about to split up the file if it is bigger then the maximum size that UDP can send, and send the split-up file one by one.

But then I am not sure what is the maximum size that UDP can send, and how could I build all the split parts back together when sending over?

```
// Client side

import os
from socket import *

//Set up information of server
server_name = '127.0.0.1'  # 127.0.0.1 is local IP
server_port = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

//Request the location of file
foundFile = 0
while foundFile == 0:
    print("========================================")
    print("[Please input the path of the file you wish to transmit.]")
    path = input("[Path]: ")
    print("========================================")

if os.path.isfile(path):
    print("[File found.]")

    fileSize = os.path.getsize(path)
    print("[File size is : ", fileSize, 'bits]')

    print("[Starting file transmission.]")
    foundFile = 1
else:
    print("[File not found.] Please re-enter the correct path.")
    print("[Please choose only on file, or enter the correct path.]")
    foundFile = 0

fileOpen = open(path, 'rb')
file = fileOpen.read()
clientSocket.sendto(file, (server_name, server_port))
```

So, if the file is small, it should send over to the server-side. Later on the code, the server-side will send the same thing back and create a copy on the desktop.

However, if the file is too big, it will give an error: 
    clientSocket.sendto(file, (server_name, server_port))
    OSError: [WinError 10040]

Comment: as I know socket may have small buffer so start with small chunk - like `4096` `(4096 = 4*1024 = 4kb)`

Comment: Just to be sure: You are aware that UDP contrary to TCP is designed as an unreliable protocol? This means that you have to deal with loss, duplication and reordering of messages yourself. Currently nothing in your code tries to cope with such problems.

Comment: Yes, TFTP. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I remember that the upper limit of bytes is ~65,000. you can divide the file in chunks and put the order in the first byte (for example).

Comment: Yes, I learned that TCP is more reliable at transfering large file then UDP. But my homework requests us to do it in UDP so...

Comment: try searching for "maximum transmission unit" or MTU, this is commonly 1500 bytes on ethernet but tends to drop to ~1490 once you hit the internet